# Xamarin Android Admob Test Ads only show once on a device

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob

I developed a Xamarin Forms App, I recently wanted to incorporate Admob Ads and used [this](https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-android/) tutorial. The iOS version works perfect, whereas the Android version only shows the Test ads once on a fresh emulator (formatted), and never appear ever again. When I create a new emulator, I only see the Ads on the 1st deployment, subsequent re-runs of the App the Ads don't show anymore. My Admob Account doesn't seem to have any issues.

The tutorial that I used is fairly old, so I had to add this snippet on the Android manifest:

```
        <application android:label="MyApp">
             <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="my admob app id ~" />
             ....
        </application>
```

The logs from the App are shown below for when the ads are not showing. I tried surfing the net with no luck, What Could be the Issue? Would appreciate the help

```
07-10 11:55:26.256 D/DynamitePackage( 4834): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
07-10 11:55:26.261 I/Ads     ( 4834): This request is sent from a test device.
07-10 11:55:26.318 I/DynamiteModule( 4834): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21001
07-10 11:55:26.318 I/DynamiteModule( 4834): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21001
07-10 11:55:27.069 W/Ads     ( 4834): JS: A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032. (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/sdk-core-v40-impl.html:0)[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/sdk-core-v40-impl.html (0)

07-10 11:55:27.069 I/chromium( 4834): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/sdk-core-v40-impl.html (0)
07-10 11:55:27.707 I/art     ( 4834): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2254(133KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 12MB/12MB, paused 7.259ms total 26.738ms
07-10 11:55:27.789 I/art     ( 4834): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 481(35KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(220KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 12MB/12MB, paused 56.403ms total 65.828ms
07-10 11:55:28.177 I/DynamiteModule( 4834): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21001
07-10 11:55:28.177 I/DynamiteModule( 4834): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21001
[0:] 
Ad just loaded = (this point is the OnLoaded() listerner event)
07-10 11:55:28.225 E/chromium( 4834): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
07-10 11:55:28.226 E/chromium( 4834): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw07-10 11:55:28.336 E/chromium( 4834): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

07-10 11:55:28.337 E/chromium( 4834): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
```

another log from a separate run:

```
07-10 12:02:22.996 D/DynamitePackage( 5094): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
07-10 12:02:23.001 I/Ads     ( 5094): This request is sent from a test device.
07-10 12:02:23.039 I/DynamiteModule( 5094): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21001
07-10 12:02:23.039 I/DynamiteModule( 5094): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21001
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/sdk-core-v40-impl.html (0)
07-10 12:02:23.798 W/Ads     ( 5094): JS: A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032. (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/sdk-core-v40-impl.html:0)
07-10 12:02:23.798 I/chromium( 5094): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/sdk-core-v40-impl.html (0)
07-10 12:02:24.374 I/art     ( 5094): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 415(25KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 12MB/12MB, paused 6.902ms total 15.970ms
07-10 12:02:24.959 I/DynamiteModule( 5094): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21001
07-10 12:02:24.959 I/DynamiteModule( 5094): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21001
[0:] 
Ad just loaded = (this point is the OnLoaded() listerner event)
[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
07-10 12:02:25.023 E/chromium( 5094): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

07-10 12:02:25.024 E/chromium( 5094): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw07-10 12:02:25.143 E/chromium( 5094): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw07-10 12:02:25.144 E/chromium( 5094): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

07-10 12:03:35.001 I/Ads     ( 5094): This request is sent from a test device.
07-10 12:03:35.944 I/DynamiteModule( 5094): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21001
07-10 12:03:35.944 I/DynamiteModule( 5094): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21001
07-10 12:03:35.962 W/Ads     ( 5094): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
07-10 12:03:35.965 W/Ads     ( 5094): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
07-10 12:03:35.966 W/Ads     ( 5094): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
[0:] 
Ad just loaded
07-10 12:03:35.992 W/Ads     ( 5094): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
07-10 12:03:35.994 W/Ads     ( 5094): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
07-10 12:03:36.478 E/chromium( 5094): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw07-10 12:03:36.480 E/chromium( 5094): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw07-10 12:03:36.586 E/chromium( 5094): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

07-10 12:03:36.587 E/chromium( 5094): [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exactly same problem and is resolved right now.

First:
1- A recommend you to use this nuget package:
https://github.com/marcojak/TestMTAdmob

2- Thr ad shows only once because you do not have a size. I resolve the problem with the exactly this code:

```
<admob:MTAdView x:Name="myAds" IsVisible="true" PersonalizedAds="true" AdsId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" >
                <admob:MTAdView.HeightRequest>
                    <x:OnIdiom>
                        <x:OnIdiom.Phone>50</x:OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <x:OnIdiom.Tablet>90</x:OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <x:OnIdiom.Desktop>90</x:OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </x:OnIdiom>
                </admob:MTAdView.HeightRequest>
            </admob:MTAdView>
```